# Using datediff with only one column and a subset of specific states

Tags: mysql, sum, datediff

I have a table called "Tickets" that looks thus:

- ticket_id: INTEGER
- to_state: VARCHAR(255)
- update_time: DATETIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE -- when the ticket entered to_state

To keep it simple, here is a set of data for one ticket.

- 135, Testing, 9 AM
- 135, Development, 10 AM
- 135, Testing, 11 AM
- 135, Closed, 12 PM

I want to sum the total amount of time (in hours) all tickets are in the "Testing" state before going to closed. So in this example the ticket spends a total of 2 hours in the "Testing" state.

What I am stuck on is that the time stamps are just one column, hence if a given ticket is in and out of "TESTING" more than once before it is closed I haven't been able to work out a useful approach.

Comment: You _really_ should have labelled this question with something which would indicate that you are stuck on a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated, because you have to get the *next* time after each "Testing" record.  I would do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.ticket_id,
       sum(timestampdiff(hour, t.next_update_time, t.update_time)) as hours
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.update_time
              from tickets t2
              where t2.ticket_id = t.ticket_id and
                    t2.to_state <> 'Testing' and
                    t2.update_time > t.update_time
              order by t2.update_time
              limit 1
             ) as next_update_time
      from tickets t
      where t.to_state = 'Testing'
     ) t
group by t.ticket_id;
```

Comment: I like this approach, I used the row_number function to be able to reference back

Answer (score 0):

Good answers, thanks. I did the following which seems to work perfectly. Thanks for the help:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME) AS Row, TICKET_ID, TO_STATE, UPDATE_TIME
INTO #A
FROM TICKETS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME) AS Row, TICKET_ID, TO_STATE, UPDATE_TIME
INTO #B
FROM TICKETS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME) AS Row, TICKET_ID, TO_STATE, UPDATE_TIME
INTO #A
FROM TICKETS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME) AS Row, TICKET_ID, TO_STATE, UPDATE_TIME
INTO #B
FROM TICKETS

SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MI, #A.UPDATE_TIME, #B.UPDATE_TIME)) AS TOTAL_MINUTES
FROM #A
LEFT JOIN #B
ON #A.ROW=#B.ROW -1
WHERE #A.TO_STATE='TESTING'
```